# procedure that returns varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions

I tried to make a function that returns `varchar`, but I can't because I'm using `CREATE  TABLE` inside, and when I'm creating it with a procedure I can't return a value.

I wanted to know if you have some advice.

I made this just to make a string with emails separated by ";" so I can have all the "manager" mails in one varchar (for the recipients).

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[Manager_email]
AS
BEGIN
    declare @mails varchar (max),
            @number_of_mails int,
            @counter int
    set @counter=2
    create table #temp ( id int identity, email varchar(30))
    insert into #temp (email)
    select Email
    from hr.Employees
    where lower (EmpRole) like 'manager'
    set @number_of_mails=@@ROWCOUNT
    set @mails = (select email from #temp where id =1 ) + ';'
    while @counter <= @number_of_mails
    BEGIN
        set @mails = @mails + (select email from #temp where id =@counter ) + ';'
        set @counter = @counter+1
    END
    drop table #temp
    return cast (@mails as varchar (200))
END
```

Comment: dont forget to mark its as acceepted if you got the information you want

Comment: You could use table variable instead of temp table,then you can use function.

Answer (score 4):

You can only return integer value back from the procedure, If you want to return varchar value from procedure its good to make use of output variable in procedure.

Example

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sales.uspGetEmployeeSalesYTD
@SalesPerson nvarchar(50),
@SalesYTD money OUTPUT
AS  

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT @SalesYTD = SalesYTD
    FROM Sales.SalesPerson AS sp
    JOIN HumanResources.vEmployee AS e ON e.BusinessEntityID = sp.BusinessEntityID
    WHERE LastName = @SalesPerson;
RETURN
```

like in above procedure return `@SalesYTD` from procedure.

you can check full post on MSDN : [**Returning Data by Using OUTPUT Parameters**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187004%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use function instead

```
CREATE FUNCTION Manager_email ()
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @email varchar(30)
    declare @emails varchar(max)

    set @emails = ''

    declare cur cursor for
    select Email
    from hr.Employees
    where lower (EmpRole) like 'manager'

    open cur

    fetch next from cur into @email

    while @@fetch_status = 0 
    begin
        set @emails = @emails + @email + ';'
        fetch next from cur into @email
    end

    close cur
    deallocate cur

    return @emails
END
```

Comment: Cursors have to be avoided. You can use `select @emails = @emails + Email from hr.Employees ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can use table variable instead of temporary table. In that case you can continue to use UDF.